# Rewrite Rule in htaccess not redirecting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have written a RewriteRule that doesn't seem to work.

The file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\/[parteneri]+)\/+([a-zA-Z\-\s]+)\/+([\/a-zA-Z\-\s]+)* index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

The line I am trying to get to work is this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(\/[parteneri]+)\/+([a-zA-Z\-\s]+)\/+([\/a-zA-Z\-\s]+)* index.php [L]
```

The Regex rule is supposed to match anything in the format: `/parteneri/event/` - I do know that the regex rule matches patterns like this one as well `/parteneri/events/asdf/adsf`, but that is fine as I would still like it to be redirected to the index page.

I have checked the regex online with a regex checker and the patterns do seem to match. The .htaccess file is on a wordpress website and I am trying to redirect every link that has `parteneri/post_type_name/` back to the index page.

Edit

I have a similar RewriteRule on another website that works, only this one has parameters as well.

```
RewriteRule ^([location]+)\/+([a-zA-Z\-\s]+)\/+([/a-zA-Z\-\s]+)*$ property-search.php?property-location=$2&sale-rent=$3 [L]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The documentation of the `RewriteRule` directive clearly states that the pattern is matched against the _relative_ path of the requested URL, if the rule is implemented in a _distributed_ configuration file (".htaccess"). That means that your rule, trying to match a leading slash ("/") can never match any request. Try that instead: `RewriteRule ^parteneri/[a-zA-Z\-\s]+/ index.php [L]`

Comment: I have added the suggested rule, but it didn't solve the issue :(

Comment: Also note that there is a difference between a "redirection" and an internal "rewrite". Your rule implements a rewrite, _not_ a redirection. If you want to _redirect_ you need to specify an according flag, something like `[R=302,L]`.

Comment: Adding the redirect flag has solved the issue, thank you arkascha! Would you be kind to elaborate a bit as to why the example I mentioned in the Edit was working in my other example?

Comment: I cannot tell you, I do not know your setup. I can only assume that the script `property-search.php` performs a redirection itself.